# Filter Custom Org Agenda View To See DONE Items in Past Week

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How can I create an Emacs org-mode custom agenda view listing DONE items completed in the past week?

Here is a simplified view of my `org-agenda-custom-commands`:

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("r" "Weekly Review"
         ((todo "DONE" ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Completed Tasks:")))))))
```

That shows me all `DONE` items. However I'd like to filter by just items completed in the past week. I am using LOGBOOK to mark items as done with a timestamp. I'd settle for just viewing DONE items that were scheduled for the past week also though.

I guess I could use `agenda` instead of a `todo` view, but I would need to get `DONE` items to show in `agenda` (they do not by default).

`org-agenda-skip-function` might work except I couldn't figure out how to get that to filter by done date - it'd be perfect otherwise.

I did see several related SO questions but I couldn't quite get any of them to work. What I really want is a simple `todo "DONE"` view as above, filtered by a date range.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I guess if you want to filter by time range you need to use an `agenda` not a `todo` command. I ended up using an `agenda` command, skipping subtrees that are not `'done` todo items:

```lisp
(org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-subtree-if 'nottodo 'done))
```

The full command looks like this:

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
        `(("r" "Weekly Review"
           ((agenda "" ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Tasks Completed:")
                        (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-subtree-if 'nottodo 'done))
                        (org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done nil)
                        (org-agenda-skip-timestamp-if-done nil)                      
                        (org-agenda-span 7)
                        (org-agenda-use-time-grid nil)
                        (setq org-agenda-show-all-dates nil)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well what you wanted, just presss `l` (lower case L) and it will activate logbook mode.

If you want to do it manually you can use something like this:

```lisp
("r" "Weekly Review"
     ((agenda "" ((org-agenda-span 7))) ;; I put this line only to help me situate in the week... 
      (tags "TODO=\"DONE\"&CLOSED>=\"<-1w>\"")
      ))
```

references:

- https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Commands.html
- https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-custom-agenda-commands.html#orge33d07b
- https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/73602/how-can-i-see-a-list-of-done-tasks-in-org-agenda-sorted-by-closed-date